# Download historical prices

Tags: historical-data, nasdaq, nyse

Is there a place I can download historical stock prices for NYSE/NASDAQ tickers at minute or lower resolution for last year or so?

Comment: free or paid? do you have access to uni library?

Comment: Free.. I don't have access to university library anymore.

Comment: google finance used to give 1 month of intraday stock data for free iirc, you could try that.